# Trim white space from label without removing inside <input>

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, innertext

My html:

```
<div class="product-addon product-addon-extra-tip">
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2004-extra-tip-0-0">
        <label><input type="radio" class="addon-radio" name="addon-2004-extra-tip-0[]" value="2"> 2 </label>
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2004-extra-donation-to-trafficking-survivors-0-1">
        <label><input type="radio" class="addon-radio" name="addon-2004-extra-tip-0[]" value="5"> 5 </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can see the label has whitespace on either side of the number.  My javascript is meant to trim only that whitespace, but it is eliminating the whole `input` tag as well.

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("div.product-addon label");
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  labels[i].textContent = labels[i].textContent.trim();
}
```

`innerText` and `innerHTML` aren't working in place of `textContent`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the docs on textContent: "Setting this property [textContent] on a node removes all of its children and replaces them with a single text node with the given value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textContent`, `innerText`, `innerHTML`, they all replace the content to whatever value you assign, so the inputs are removed.

What you should be doing, is iterating over the childnodes, filtering out just textnodes, and trimming the contents of those only.

```js
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("div.product-addon label");
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var children = labels[i].childNodes;
 
    for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
     if ( children[j].nodeType === 3 ) 
         children[j].nodeValue = children[j].nodeValue.trim();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="product-addon product-addon-extra-tip">
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2004-extra-tip-0-0">
        <label><input type="radio" class="addon-radio" name="addon-2004-extra-tip-0[]" value="2"> 2 </label>
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2004-extra-donation-to-trafficking-survivors-0-1">
        <label><input type="radio" class="addon-radio" name="addon-2004-extra-tip-0[]" value="5"> 5 </label>
    </p>
</div>
```